# DateTimePicker does not close when pressing 'OK' button

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use `DateTimePicker` from this library

```
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
```

and the problem is with `android`. When I press the `OK` button - it sets the selected date properly, but it does not close - otherwise it disappear for a second and opens again. I need to press `cancel` to turn off datetime window. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
const [mode, setMode] = useState('date')
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
const [pickedDate, setPickedDate] = useState('Pick date')
const [pickedTime, setPickedTime] = useState('Pick time')

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date

    setDate(currentDate)

    const days = String(selectedDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
    const month = String(selectedDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
    const year = selectedDate.getFullYear()

    const formattedDate = year + '/' + month + '/' + days
    setPickedDate(formattedDate)

    const hours = selectedDate.getHours()
    const minutes = selectedDate.getMinutes()
    const formattedTime = (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours) + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes)
    setPickedTime(formattedTime)
}
```

```
{ show && (
<DateTimePicker
    value={date}
    mode={mode}
    is24Hour={true}
    display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'spinner' : 'default'}
    onChange={(event, date) => onChange(event, date)}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check event type of `onChange` function. And handle it accordingly.

```
if(event.type == "set") {
    //ok button clicked
} else {
    //cancel button clicked
}
```

Comment: thanks for advice, but the result is the same - window closes for a second and opens again

Comment: @John where do you call `setShow(false)` in your code

Comment: I used `setShow(false)` at the end of `onChange` method and it closes the window but it looks like this: `hidden` -> `showed again for milisecond` -> `hidden again until I turn on the window again`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the show to false on the onChange but make sure to call this BEFORE you set the values. I fixed this for Date mode by following this answer from:
https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/54

[image]